# Should I create a model when using Guzzle to consume an API?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, guzzle

I want to make a simple web app that consumes a restful api, and displays the data on a webpage.

I'm using Laravel with Guzzle to consume the api. In my controller I'm essentially doing this:

```
$client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
$result = $client->post('your-request-uri', [
    'form_params' => [
    'sample-form-data' => 'value'
    ]
]);
```

Should I create a model using the returned data. Or should I just hand back the data straight to my frontend?

I'm not storing any data but I do want to do some validation of the returned data.

If you were consuming an API to pass to a frontend and needed to do some sever side validation on the data returned how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a subjective question. If it's just some simple logic / validation, a pragmatic approach would be to just do this in the controller and pass it to the view directly.

If the complexity increases in the future you could move it in a Model.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create model you can directly pass to view from controller to results.